Absolute and conditional convergence of a non-alternating series
I tried all tests such as d'Alembert test, Cauchy test, Leibniz test,... but i could't determine convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}$$
Can you help me!!!

Hint: Note that $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}=\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}(-1)^n}$. The original series converges if and only if the series of the term on the right converges. (why?) And the convergence of the latter series (which is a series of nonnegative terms) is easy to check using a limit comparison test.

I'm understood, thank you for your answer

$\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))$
From this you can continue by using comparison theorem and alternating series the  you will prove that you sum diverges.

Oh, tks so muchhhh
